# How to write correct query to filter data in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to filter data of brokers. The filter has dropdown for CITY & LOCALITY (dependent dropdown of CITY) and many checkboxes to filter. I need to show brokers of a CITY and LOCALITY (if locality is selected), all the brokers who have any of the selected filters in their profile. Presently the code is not showing all the brokers and is having AND logic. All the filter checkboxes have individual fields in broker table. What is the correct query? I would like to show all the brokers even if CITY is not selected (I mean I need to show all the cities brokers).

```
        $brokers = User::whereRoleIs('broker')
            ->when($city, function ($query) use ($city) {
                $query->where('city', $city);
            })
            ->when($locality, function ($query) use ($locality) {
                $query->where('locality', $locality);
            })
            ->when($plots, function ($query) use ($plots) {
                $query->where('plots', $plots);
            })
            ->when($apartments, function ($query) use ($apartments) {
                $query->where('apartments', $apartments);
            })
            ->when($agricultureland, function ($query) use ($agricultureland) {
                $query->where('agricultureland', $agricultureland);
            })
            ->when($internationalproperties, function ($query) use ($internationalproperties) {
                $query->where('internationalproperties', $internationalproperties);
            })
            ->when($industrial, function ($query) use ($industrial) {
                $query->where('industrial', $industrial);
            })
            ->when($commercial, function ($query) use ($commercial) {
                $query->where('commercial', $commercial);
            })
            ->when($residential, function ($query) use ($residential) {
                $query->where('residential', $residential);
            })
            ->when($rent, function ($query) use ($rent) {
                $query->where('rent', $rent);
            })
            ->when($buysell, function ($query) use ($buysell) {
                $query->where('buysell', $buysell);
            })
            ->when($primary, function ($query) use ($primary) {
                $query->where('primary', $primary);
            })
            ->when($secondary, function ($query) use ($secondary) {
                $query->where('secondary', $secondary);
            })
            ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(25)
            ->withQueryString();
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not passing empty variables (ex. **''**  ) to the "when" function?
because if  `$city=''` then `$query->where('city', $city)` is like `where city=''` and would likely to return nothing.  Make sure your parameters for `when` is`null`

Comment: Thanks for your time. Do you mean I should have 'null' as default values in the table ?

Comment: no, I mean watch what variable you are passing to the `when` because if you pass an empty string (ex. `''`) you will retrieve nothing